# app name and main activity title can be different in Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to have different app name and main activity title ?

I had tried to change `manifest` file, to find work-around like `setTitle()` to the `ActionBar`, but expected result not happens. I think this string must be identical, isn't it ?

Anyone can tell me about this,if can make it,please tell me how to do?Thanks!

**UPDATE:** snippet from manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.myname.appname"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_home_activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.DetailsPageActivity"
                  android:parentActivityName=".activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_details"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are your sure value of `app_name` and `title_home_activity` are different?

Comment: What's the parent of your `HomeActivity`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I see strange behaviour: The name of the app at the home screen and title in the main activity is absolutely the same `title_home_activity`, but when I longTap on icon in the home screen and swipe to delete or to see app details the name of the app is `app_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can make these different by configuring in `manifest.xml`, your application name depends on this attribute `android:label` in `application` tag, like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >  <!--application name-->
```

ActionBar title depends on `android:label` in `activity` tag, like this:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_name" > <!--actionbar title-->
```

So if you set two attributes to different string, they will be different.

Consider your case, you can try this:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/activity_name" > <!--actionbar title-->
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/activity_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn`t works for me. I have two different strings, but app behaviour set for both cases laber from <application> tag

Comment: Solution founded, there is a mistake in intent filter: instead of label "activity_name" need "app_name" and all works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this aim is - Set **activity name** via MainActivity.Java, Set **app name** via AndroidMainfest.xml

*Note* - **Uninstall** current apk from the phone and **reinstall** it for the app name to change

---

Main Activity.Java (Put this code in **onCreate** method)

> this.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.activity_name));

---

AndroidManifest.xml (Notice **android:label** attribute)

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

---

Strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Enter Name Here</string>
<string name="activity_name">Enter Name Here</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a single Application have multiple activities for different uses and each activity has its own actionbar which represents the header title about the activity so, is the different Application and activity title. To set the title of an activity you can call `setTitle()` at runtime inside activity's `oncreate` or anywhere you want.

For application name you can add `android:label="@string/app_name"` under the application tag and specify the `app_name` string in values.
The same line `(android:label="@string/Activity_name")` under the activity tag in the `manifest file` takes the title of the actionbar of that particular activity.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can alter the title in the resource file. In android studio it's located in app/res/values/strings.xml. Normally there is a string called "app_name".