# Different labels for icon and main activity in android 7

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

as seen in [app name and main activity title can be different in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129301/app-name-and-main-activity-title-can-be-different-in-android) i can define different labels for icon and main activity.

Since android 7 it seems the label of the intent-filter is ignored, and the label of the main activity is used as icon text.

Is there an workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open issue on the Issue Tracker ([Issue 37121213](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37121213)) for API level 24 and above. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#iconlabel), it *should* work the way you described:

> …a filter with `android.intent.action.MAIN` and
>   `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` settings advertises an activity as
>   one that initiates an application. That is, as one that should be
>   displayed in the application launcher. The icon and label that are set
>   in the filter are displayed in the launcher.

I do not know of a workaround that will allow you to create separate labels for the `intent-filter` and `activity` labels within the manifest. But you can set the label you would like to appear in the application launcher in the `activity` tag, then just set the title for the `Activity` in your Java code.